# SVG and JQuery GIF fill running slower on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, svg, gif, fill

I built an interactive SVG with fill properties that change on the hovering over of each group. It performs properly on my Wordpress site in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the GIFs set as fill are choppy and the SVG as a whole is not as responsive. What is going wrong here?

Strangely enough, it performs better when the Web Inspector is open on my site in Firefox AND when running the code snippet on this page in Firefox. My site seems to be producing the problem.

[My Site](https://ijdonnelly.com)

```js
function preloadImages(array) {
    if (!preloadImages.list) {
        preloadImages.list = [];
    }
    var list = preloadImages.list;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        list.push(img);
        img.src = array[i];
    }
}

preloadImages(['https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/together.gif',
    'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/reflekt.gif',
    'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/harp.gif',
    'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/card.gif',
    'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/alien.gif',
    'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/a3.gif',
    'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png'
    ]);

var sOne = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png';
var lOne = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/card.gif';
  
var sTwo = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png';
var lTwo = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/together.gif';

var sThree = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png';
var lThree = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/reflekt.gif';

var sFour = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png';
var lFour = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/antmin-1.gif';

var sFive = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png';
var lFive = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/harp.gif';

var sSix = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png';
var lSix = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/alien.gif';

var sSeven = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png';
var lSeven = 'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/a3.gif';

$(function() {
    $('#one').hover(function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', lOne);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', lOne);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', lOne);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', lOne);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', lOne);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', lOne);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', lOne);
            
            $(".dOne").fadeIn("slow");
            
        },
        function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', sOne);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', sTwo);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', sThree);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', sFour);
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', sFive);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', sSix);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', sSeven);
            $('.dOne').fadeOut('fast');


        });
});

$(function() {
    $('#two').hover(function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', lTwo);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', lTwo);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', lTwo);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', lTwo);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', lTwo);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', lTwo);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', lTwo);
            
        },
        function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', sOne);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', sTwo);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', sThree);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', sFour);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', sFive);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', sSix);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', sSeven);
            

        });
});


$(function() {
    $('#three').hover(function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', lThree);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', lThree);
          
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', lThree);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', lThree);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', lThree);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', lThree);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', lThree);
            
        },
        function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', sOne);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', sTwo);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', sThree);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', sFour);
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', sFive);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', sSix);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', sSeven);

        });
});

$(function() {
    $('#four').hover(function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', lFour);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', lFour);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', lFour);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', lFour);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', lFour);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', lFour);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', lFour);
            
        },
        function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', sOne);
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', sTwo);
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', sThree);
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', sFour);
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', sFive);
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', sSix);
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', sSeven);

        });
});


$(function() {
    $('#five').hover(function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', lFive);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', lFive);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', lFive);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', lFive);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', lFive);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', lFive);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', lFive);
            
        },
        function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', sOne);
        
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', sTwo);

            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', sThree);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', sFour);
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', sFive);
    
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', sSix);

            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', sSeven);

        });
});

$(function() {
    $('#six').hover(function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', lSix);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', lSix);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', lSix);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', lSix);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', lSix);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', lSix);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', lSix);
            
        },
        function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', sOne);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', sTwo);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', sThree);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', sFour);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', sFive);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', sSix);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', sSeven);
            

        });
});

$(function() {
    $('#seven').hover(function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', lSeven);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', lSeven);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', lSeven);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', lSeven);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', lSeven);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', lSeven);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', lSeven);
            
        },
        function() {
            var value = $('#img1 image');
            value.attr('xlink:href', sOne);
            
            var value2 = $('#img2 image');
            value2.attr('xlink:href', sTwo);
            
            var value3 = $('#img3 image');
            value3.attr('xlink:href', sThree);
            
            var value4 = $('#img4 image');
            value4.attr('xlink:href', sFour);
            
            var value5 = $('#img5 image');
            value5.attr('xlink:href', sFive);
            
            var value6 = $('#img6 image');
            value6.attr('xlink:href', sSix);
            
            var value7 = $('#img7 image');
            value7.attr('xlink:href', sSeven);
            
        });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #edeeef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crys">
        <svg id="crystal" width="500px" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1552.59 1053.68" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/22/a3-logo-animation/">
            <polyline points="154.59 396.52 154.59 291.75 77.29 239.37 0 291.75 0 396.52 0.27 396.7 0 396.7 0 658.44 0 694.63 0 763.21 77.29 815.59 154.59 763.21 154.59 658.44" fill="url(#img1)" id="one" />
            </a>
            <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/21/together-after-effects-short-film/">
          <polyline points="387.58 295.93 387.58 191.16 310.29 138.78 233 191.16 233 295.93 233.27 296.11 233 296.11 233 759.02 233 779.94 233 863.79 310.29 916.17 387.58 863.79 387.58 759.02" fill="url(#img2)" id="two" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/21/afterglow-maya-premiere/">
          <polyline points="620.59 232.27 620.59 127.5 543.29 75.12 466 127.5 466 232.27 466.27 232.45 466 232.45 466 823.96 466 876.7 466 928.72 543.29 981.11 620.59 928.72 620.59 823.96" fill="url(#img3)" id="three" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2017/10/03/scanning-electron-microscopy-to-vr-assets/">
          <polyline points="853.59 157.15 853.59 52.38 776.29 0 699 52.38 699 143.33 699 157.15 699 896.53 699 905.99 699 1001.3 776.29 1053.68 853.59 1001.3 853.59 896.53 853.06 896.17" fill="url(#img4)" id="four" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/18/dslr-automata-max-msp/">
          <polyline points="1398 658.44 1398 763.21 1475.29 815.59 1552.59 763.21 1552.59 658.44 1552.32 658.26 1552.59 658.26 1552.59 396.52 1552.59 360.32 1552.59 291.75 1475.29 239.37 1398 291.75 1398 396.52" fill="url(#img5)" id="five" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2017/10/03/melodi-musical-puzzle-game-unity-c/">
          <polyline points="1165 759.02 1165 863.79 1242.29 916.17 1319.59 863.79 1319.59 759.02 1319.32 758.84 1319.59 758.84 1319.59 295.93 1319.59 275.02 1319.59 191.16 1242.29 138.78 1165 191.16 1165 295.93" fill="url(#img6)" id="six" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/18/musical-water-fountain/">
          <polyline points="932 822.68 932 927.45 1009.29 979.83 1086.59 927.45 1086.59 822.68 1086.32 822.5 1086.59 822.5 1086.59 231 1086.59 178.25 1086.59 126.23 1009.29 73.85 932 126.23 932 231" fill="url(#img7)" id="seven" />
          </a>
          <defs>
            <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000" rotation="50deg">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="img3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="img4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="img5" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="img6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="img7" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
          </defs>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you experience performance lags due to not optimised code. Consider following changes:

1. You don't want to use exactly the same mask individually for every segment; use one mask instead and apply it to all segments
2. Create second mask for animation
3. Create clone of your 'crystal' and set its fill to second mask
4. Hide cloned crystals by default
5. When hovered, apply a new image to second mask and show cloned crystals
6. Apply transition time to mask fading for better experience
7. Don't use separate JQuery functions for every crystal - do it at once for all

After applying all of it - you won't notice lags in Firefox anymore

```js
function preloadImages(array) {
    if (!preloadImages.list) {
        preloadImages.list = [];
    }
    var list = preloadImages.list;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        list.push(img);
        img.src = array[i];
    }
}

var slides = [
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/card.gif',
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/together.gif',
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/reflekt.gif',
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/antmin-1.gif',
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/harp.gif',
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/alien.gif',
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/a3.gif',
  'https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png'
]

preloadImages(slides);

var $mask = $('#img2 image');
var $clip = $('.clip');

$(function() {
    $('svg a').hover(
      function(){
        $mask.attr('xlink:href', slides[$(this).index()]);
        $clip.css('opacity', 1);
      },
      function(){
        $clip.css('opacity', 0);
      }
    );
      
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #edeeef;
}
.clip {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms opacity linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crys">
        <svg id="crystal" width="500px" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1552.59 1053.68" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/22/a3-logo-animation/">
            <polyline points="154.59 396.52 154.59 291.75 77.29 239.37 0 291.75 0 396.52 0.27 396.7 0 396.7 0 658.44 0 694.63 0 763.21 77.29 815.59 154.59 763.21 154.59 658.44" fill="url(#img1)" />
              <polyline points="154.59 396.52 154.59 291.75 77.29 239.37 0 291.75 0 396.52 0.27 396.7 0 396.7 0 658.44 0 694.63 0 763.21 77.29 815.59 154.59 763.21 154.59 658.44" fill="url(#img2)" class="clip" />
            </a>
            <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/21/together-after-effects-short-film/">
          <polyline points="387.58 295.93 387.58 191.16 310.29 138.78 233 191.16 233 295.93 233.27 296.11 233 296.11 233 759.02 233 779.94 233 863.79 310.29 916.17 387.58 863.79 387.58 759.02" fill="url(#img1)" />
              <polyline points="387.58 295.93 387.58 191.16 310.29 138.78 233 191.16 233 295.93 233.27 296.11 233 296.11 233 759.02 233 779.94 233 863.79 310.29 916.17 387.58 863.79 387.58 759.02" fill="url(#img2)" class="clip" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/21/afterglow-maya-premiere/">
          <polyline points="620.59 232.27 620.59 127.5 543.29 75.12 466 127.5 466 232.27 466.27 232.45 466 232.45 466 823.96 466 876.7 466 928.72 543.29 981.11 620.59 928.72 620.59 823.96" fill="url(#img1)" />
            <polyline points="620.59 232.27 620.59 127.5 543.29 75.12 466 127.5 466 232.27 466.27 232.45 466 232.45 466 823.96 466 876.7 466 928.72 543.29 981.11 620.59 928.72 620.59 823.96" fill="url(#img2)" class="clip" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2017/10/03/scanning-electron-microscopy-to-vr-assets/">
          <polyline points="853.59 157.15 853.59 52.38 776.29 0 699 52.38 699 143.33 699 157.15 699 896.53 699 905.99 699 1001.3 776.29 1053.68 853.59 1001.3 853.59 896.53 853.06 896.17" fill="url(#img1)" />
            <polyline points="853.59 157.15 853.59 52.38 776.29 0 699 52.38 699 143.33 699 157.15 699 896.53 699 905.99 699 1001.3 776.29 1053.68 853.59 1001.3 853.59 896.53 853.06 896.17" fill="url(#img2)" class="clip" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/18/dslr-automata-max-msp/">
          <polyline points="1398 658.44 1398 763.21 1475.29 815.59 1552.59 763.21 1552.59 658.44 1552.32 658.26 1552.59 658.26 1552.59 396.52 1552.59 360.32 1552.59 291.75 1475.29 239.37 1398 291.75 1398 396.52" fill="url(#img1)" />
            <polyline points="1398 658.44 1398 763.21 1475.29 815.59 1552.59 763.21 1552.59 658.44 1552.32 658.26 1552.59 658.26 1552.59 396.52 1552.59 360.32 1552.59 291.75 1475.29 239.37 1398 291.75 1398 396.52" fill="url(#img2)" class="clip" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2017/10/03/melodi-musical-puzzle-game-unity-c/">
          <polyline points="1165 759.02 1165 863.79 1242.29 916.17 1319.59 863.79 1319.59 759.02 1319.32 758.84 1319.59 758.84 1319.59 295.93 1319.59 275.02 1319.59 191.16 1242.29 138.78 1165 191.16 1165 295.93" fill="url(#img1)" />
            <polyline points="1165 759.02 1165 863.79 1242.29 916.17 1319.59 863.79 1319.59 759.02 1319.32 758.84 1319.59 758.84 1319.59 295.93 1319.59 275.02 1319.59 191.16 1242.29 138.78 1165 191.16 1165 295.93" fill="url(#img2)" class="clip" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ijdonnelly.com/2018/01/18/musical-water-fountain/">
          <polyline points="932 822.68 932 927.45 1009.29 979.83 1086.59 927.45 1086.59 822.68 1086.32 822.5 1086.59 822.5 1086.59 231 1086.59 178.25 1086.59 126.23 1009.29 73.85 932 126.23 932 231" fill="url(#img1)" />
            <polyline points="932 822.68 932 927.45 1009.29 979.83 1086.59 927.45 1086.59 822.68 1086.32 822.5 1086.59 822.5 1086.59 231 1086.59 178.25 1086.59 126.23 1009.29 73.85 932 126.23 932 231" fill="url(#img2)" class="clip" />
          </a>
          <defs>
            <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2000" height="2000">
              <image xlink:href="https://ijdonnelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cover2.png" x="-223" y="-500" width="2000" height="2000" />
            </pattern>
          </defs>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxJebX)

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. Thank you so so much! I can't believe you added the fade as well; that is something I've been trying to accomplish for a long time! I can't wait to put this into use.